# Dynamic macros with csname and utf-8

Tags: macros, hyperref, unicode

I wrote the following commands for dynamic variable names and assignment

```
% in class file
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% in latex file
\newcommand{\rev}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname{#2}
}

\newcommand{\grev}[1]{%
  \ifcsname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname%
  \csname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname
\fi}
```

This works for well for ASCII characters, e.g.

```
\rev{value1}{Test}
\grev{value1} % gives Test
```

but not for Umlauts (only in \rev)

```
\rev{value2}{Groß}
\grev{value2} % gives GroT1ss
```

I know, it has something to do with the internal character representation and expansion but I could not find out how to fix this. Any ideas?

**Update [2014-01-15]**

It is

```
\newcommand{\revprefix}{}
```

The problem only occurs in a TextField of hyperref:

```
\TextField[name=test, value=\grev{value2}]{test}
```

Comment: I don't get anything strange; `\grev{value2}` prints “Groß” as expected. What's `\revprefix`?

Comment: It's empty: `\newcommand{\revprefix}{}`. But you are right! This problem only occurs in a Textfield. I will update the problem description.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `\grev`: also `\TextField[name=test, value=Groß]{test}` shows the same problem.

Comment: Right. So, the problem is the wrong encoding!?

Comment: When I define a temporary macro by `\defpdfstring{\tmpval}{\grev{value2}}` und use `\tmpval` in `\TextField` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different way to produce the string, with `\defpdfstring`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\revprefix}{}

\newcommand{\rev}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\pdfstringdef\csname tfrev_\revprefix#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\grev}[1]{%
  \ifcsname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname
    \csname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname
  \fi}
\newcommand{\tfgrev}[1]{%
  \ifcsname rev_\revprefix#1\endcsname
    \csname tfrev_\revprefix#1\endcsname
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\rev{value1}{Test}
\grev{value1} % gives Test

\rev{value2}{Groß}
\grev{value2}

\TextField[name=test, value=\tfgrev{value2}]{test}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you don't need `\grev` other than in text forms, defining `\grev` is  useless.